# Connect Odroid to internet via ethernet shared connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, connection-sharing

This previously was working and has now stopped; I can't figure out which setting has become somehow corrupted. I have an Odroid connected to a Windows 10 PC over ethernet. I want to share the internet (WIFI) connection of the PC to the Odroid. The network configuration is

```
Odroid:
IP (static): 192.168.137.66
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.137.1

PC (ethernet):
IP (static) 192.168.137.1
Mask 255.255.255.0

PC (WIFI; internet connection sharing enabled)
IP (DHCP) 192.168.20.2
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway (Router): 192.168.20.1

PC Firewall rule (inbound): allow all traffic over LAN interface type
```

I can ping back and forward between the ordoid and the PC, however the Odroid cannot get out to the internet. Am I right to think that if the Odroid and PC are pinging, the WIFI connection is shared and the gateway set as above then this should just work or am I missing something?